# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow()'

Tags: c#

I Get this error `Error 1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow()'`

I get that error on Process.CloseMainWindow();

Could you tell me where my mistake is? I'm trying to make it that when you click x on the c# win form app it to kill the process.

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.CloseMainWindow();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There are better ways to close the application, e.g. `Application.Exit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Process` class is used to handle external processes.

You need to get the Process you want to close.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("myProcess").FirstOrDefault();
if (process != null)
{
    process.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

But if you are closing a child form and you want it to exit your application use

```
 Environment.Exit(0);// or whatever exit code you need
```

or  as  @Nico Schertler metioned

```
 Application.Exit();
```

But if this is your main form and you click `X` is should close without any other code.

Comment: Thanks, used the nico schertler suggestion. Also it's not my main form, it's a second form which ends up leaving the process running even tho i close it.

Answer (score 0):

I used Application.Exit(); - just as Nico Schertler said. (Thanks btw)

Here's the working code:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must change your method to static

```
private static void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     Process.CloseMainWindow();
}
```

Comment: I get more errors from the ** ** and the Process.CloseMainWindow();